# SSRS Report - Calculating row difference

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report

I'm trying to create a report in SSRS based on a simple concept.  I have categories which have Available Budget Amount.  As estimates become actual expenditures the Available Budget Amount get's decreases by what was spent.

Details below.

[Presentational View Of The Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCrgC.png)

Goal:
To have [Available Budget Amount] calculated properly.

Notes:
We start out with Available Budget Amount for each Category group.  As we move down the child rows, we take the previous row’s Available Budget Amount and subtract from [Actual Cost] or use [Cost Estimate] if [Actual Cost] is empty.

Things I tried:

1) Using Previous () function - works only if we have one child node.

2) Expressions - Does not use previous Available Budget Amount in calculations.

Question:  What do I need to use in order to get Available Budget Amount column to render in SSRS with correct amount?

Any advice, code or example, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jimmy

Comment: Have you considered the SSRS function `RunningValue()`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow...#SOReadyToHelp